# Use VBA in Google Sheets to auto

Tags: excel, vba, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get a google doc to include an auto-fill of that day's date whenever a value in a row is changed.

I found an excel VBA code that does the trick (below). However, it won't work in google sheets.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Row > 1 Then Cells(Target.Row, "B") = Date
End Sub
```

Do you know how to make this work in sheets, either as  function or as code?

Answer (score 3):

Google Sheets does not support **VBA** -- which stands for Visual Basic for Applications, a Microsoft language derived from Visual Basic.

What Sheets **does** support is Javascript functions working just as macros.

[Check this out](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros) for more information on Javascript macros.