# How to use VBA in Google Sheets to highlight cells with special characters and uppercase letters?

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets, google-sheets-conditionalformatting

I managed to get a VBA-snippet working in Microsoft Excel that highlights all Cells in Range C1 to E10000 which contain anything else than lowercase a–z, numbers and hyphens.

The code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SpecialChars()
    Dim RangeToCheck As Range, c As Range

Set RangeToCheck = Range("C1:E10000")
For Each c In RangeToCheck
    If Len(c.Text) > 0 Then
        If c.Text Like "*[!.a-z0-9\-]*" Then
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else: c.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    End If
Next c
End Sub
```

What is the proper way to transfer this to Google Sheets? I think the problem might be, that Google uses JavaScript while Excel uses something else.

Still I wanted to give it a shot here.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself yet but [this](https://scand.com/products/gspread/) apparently lets you use VBA in google sheets.

Comment: why is this tagged javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use VBA in Google Sheets to auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261465/use-vba-in-google-sheets-to-auto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need scripts. You could use conditional formatting.  It seems the only reason you're using `VBA` is because you need `REGEX`, which Microsoft excel doesn't support except  through  `VBA`.  Google Sheets however has `REGEX` support inbuilt.

> ...  highlights all Cells in Range C1 to E10000 which contain anything else than lowercase a–z, numbers and hyphens....

#### **Conditional formatting >Custom formula**:

```
=REGEXMATCH(C1,"^[a-z0-9\-]+$")
```

This will be used to match

- Lowercase
- Numbers
- Hyphen (-)

Highlight yellow
Apply to range: C1:E10000

Note: Spaces are not matched. So, If you have spaces, It will not match.

Comment: This makes things a lot easier! Thank you very much for your kind help. Is there also an option to exclude the occurrence of doubled characters? Like allow the caracter "." but not ".."?

Comment: Thanks very much that works like a charm!

In case i want to add more restrictions like not allowing "--" i just add more logical expressions right?

The "." is not at the end cause I am setting up a sheet for URL verification :D

Comment: I’ve done so! Thanks again. Following question: If I want to set this up like a template for people to fill in a list of 1000 URLs or so, can I arrange this like an array or something? Because right now I have to set it up for 1000 rows and by default I, of course, get "FALSE" and "#VALUE" error as long as the accordant cell is empty and not filled in. This is just a usability/aesthetic factor of course.

Comment: Here I’ve set up a [Sample Google-Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SbnEMLNK2qyTJdir-zLSsROXwJLobGaVa_KJFML1PSE/edit?usp=sharing).
As you can see I would prefer the sheet only to apply the rule whenever I enter URLs in column A.
I have tried it like this: `ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A,AND(NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2,"\-{2,}")),NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2,"\.{2,}")),REGEXMATCH(A2,"^[a-z0-9\-\/\:\.\=\?]+$")),""))`

Comment: thanks! I have changed that. However it does not seem to work. As I see I was thinking too twisted :D As it appeares I don’t even need my B column though. Things are getting more elegant with every edit :)

Answer (score -1):

If you work in Google Apps, you should better do it via the **GAS** (Google Apps Script). That is the JavaScript based Google's equivalent to VBA.